# Powershell как выводить сообщения при запуске блокнота (либо другого приложения)

Tags: windows, powershell

Powershell как выводить сообщение при запуске блокнота (либо другого приложения).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
register-wmiEvent -query "select * from __instancecreationevent within 5 where targetinstance isa 'Win32_Process' and targetinstance.name='notepad.exe'" -sourceIdentifier "ProcessStarted" -Action { Write-Host "RUNNING" }
```